# can an Integer ID, auto increment, primary key on MYSQL start with 0+number?

Tags: mysql, formatting

I am trying to figure out if is possible to set an Integer, auto increment as primary key, could start with 0? like 01, 02,0234324 ?

Is it possible??

Should a numeric ID , that is also a primary key have that format? Dont know if possible, but in case it is, would it be a good practice?

Thanks

Comment: You could try it. It truncates the leading zero (not my downvote).

Comment: If an auto-incremented id has *any* meaning outside the internal scope of the database, then DO NOT use AUTO_INCREMENT for constructing it.

Comment: why not auto_increment @Strawberry ? could you be more specific?

Comment: Let's start with another question. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to know if is possible, if is a good practice or is something to avoid

Comment: It's bad practice, and something to avoid. A user wouldn't ordinarily need to see the values generated in an auto-incrementing column

Comment: its not for a user or to make it easier for the developer to later use this number or anything, I just saw it and wanted to know if there is a special reason for it or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL an auto-increment field has to be an integer. For an integer there is no difference between 02 and 2 as far as storage is concerned. However, you can change the default display using the `ZEROFILL` attribute like this:

```
> create table t1 (n int(11) zerofill not null auto_increment primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

> insert into t1 values (null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

> select * from t1;
+-------------+
| n           |
+-------------+
| 00000000001 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any convention that says is a bad practice? or could be acceptable?

Comment: This is something I would not do. I do not like to have the database format things for me. If I need a certain format I would use a special function, e.g LPAD() in this case.

Comment: I can think of no situation where you would ordinarily need to present an auto-incremented id to a user